# 'App not Installed' error for release apk but working fine for Debug apk

Tags: android, android-studio

I have already install my app in Redmi 4A with USB.
Now i am installing release.apk but while installing 'App not installed' error is showing.
I have checked in both the versions (v1 and v2).
Strange Part it is that the same configuration is working perfectly fine when i am installing debug.apk
Please help and guide me through this.

Comment: When you are trying to install the release apk, is the debug apk already present on device? If yes, the delete the debug apk first since both have different signatures, so would an error if you try to install release build when debug is already present on same device.

Comment: No Shobhit, I uninstalled previous versions before installing new versions.

Comment: Did you uninstall from the home screen by dragging or by going into settings -> apps? Can you double check the apps section in your settings app if there is nothing remaining of the old app?

Comment: Shobhit, I have done both ways for uninstallation dragging and going to app sections. I have double checked in app section if any remains of my app or package name is still available. I need to find some different ways.